# Pythonで1つ上の階層のディレクトリ名のみ取得したい

Tags: python

```
from pathlib import Path
Path(__file__).parents[2] = '\\hoge0\hoge1'
Path(__file__).parents[1] = '\\hoge0\hoge1\hoge2'
Path(__file__).parents[0] = '\\hoge0\hoge1\hoge2\hoge3'
```

'hoge2'を取得したいのですが、
`str(Path(__file__).parents[1]).replace(str(Path(__file__).parents[2]),'')`
は書き方的にスマートでないと思います。
他にも、正規表現で取得するというのもくどい気がします。
実はpathlibの中の関数で簡単に取得できる、ということはないでしょうか。
osモジュールの利用でも構いません。

**実行環境**

- Windows 10
- Python 3.7

Comment: pathlib を使うのでしたら `Path(__file__).resolve().parents[1].stem` とします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.path`モジュールを使う方法です。

```
from os.path import abspath, join, split

split(abspath(join(__file__, '../..')))[-1]
```